# Colocar valor numa caixa de texto (input)

Tags: javascript

Quero colocar um valor numa caixa de texto.

```
function open_popup(date_today){

        document.getElementById('txtstart').value = date_today;
    }
```

e a input html

```
<input type=text required name='txtstart' style='width:150px' value=''>
```

A caixa de texto esta numa div que esta escondida, e é vista quando a funcao open_popup() é executada. Nao sei porque isto nao funciona.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Está à procura do elemento pela ID (`getElementById`), mas o elemento não tem ID...

Pode usar assim:

```
document.querySelector("[name='txtstart']").value = date_today;
```

ou então dar uma ID ao elemento, acrescentando `id="txtstart"`  no HTML do input.

Exemplo:

```js
function open_popup(date_today) {
    document.querySelector("[name='txtstart']").value = date_today;
}

open_popup('2014-10-14');
alert(document.querySelector("[name='txtstart']").value);
```

```html
<div style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" required name="txtstart" style="width:150px" value="">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

mude para:

```
function open_popup(date_today){

    $("#txtstart").val(date_today);
}
```

e no input:

```
<input type=text required name='txtstart' id='txtstart' style='width:150px' value=''>
```

Answer (score 1):

Para usar `document.getElementById('exemplo')` você tem que passar o ID da caixa de input, não o name. Você pode fazer assim:

```
<input type=text required name='txtstart' id='txtstart' style='width:150px' value=''>
```

Answer (score -4):

Adicione isto (onsubmit="return valida_form(this)") em seu form.

EX:

```
<form name="index" method="post" action="nextpage.php" id="index" onsubmit="return valida_form(this)">
```