# Colocar um variável no value de um input

Tags: javascript, html5

Tenho uma variável, por exemplo:

```
 let exemplo = document.querySelector("#id");
```

Quero pergar o valor desta variável e colocar no `value` de um *input* HTML:

```
<input type="text" valeu="receberia o valor da variável exemplo" />
```

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/37758/colocar-valor-numa-caixa-de-texto-input

Comment: Eu olhei, mas não sei como resolve meu problema... Não tem como colocar direto o no value o valor da minha variável?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só você atribuir o novo valor ao atributo `value` do objeto que representa o seu campo. Veja um exemplo abaixo:

```js
const novoValor = "Stack Overflow em Português";
const campo = document.getElementById("campo");

campo.value = novoValor;
```

```html
<input id="campo" value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

Sem jquery seria assim:

```js
var texto = 'abc';
var elemento = document.getElementById('iddoinput');
elemento.value = texto
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
   var exemplo = document.querySelector("#id");
    
    document.querySelector("[name='txtstart']").value = exemplo;
```

```html
 
    
    <input type="text" required name="txtstart" style="width:150px" value="">
```